# How to display number after clicking button multiple times in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I have this little code where I'm trying to display a number after clicking on on particular buttons for specified times. I have done this through if conditions but I'm pretty sure that this isn't the most efficient way of doing it. In my code All I've done is display a number each and everytime a button is clicked. What I want for example is to display a the number 1 after pressing the button 33 times and display the number 2 when another 33 clicks are registered and so on.

```
package engineers.android.com.azkar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Sebh extends Activity {
TextView textView;
TextView textView_sum;
TextView textView1;
TextView textView_sum1;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView_sum2;
Context context = this;
int coun1=0;
int coun2=0;
int coun3=0;
int sum1=0;
int sum2=0;
int sum3=0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sebhah);

    Button bhome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bh);
    bhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.c1);
    textView_sum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.s1);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c2);
    textView_sum1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s2);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c3);
    textView_sum2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s3);

}

public void s5(View view) {
    coun1++;
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(coun1));
    if (coun1 == 33 ) {
        sum1=1;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }else if (coun1 == 66 ) {
        sum1=2;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }else if (coun1 == 99 ) {
        sum1=3;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }else if (coun1 == 132 ) {
        sum1=4;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }else if (coun1 == 165 ) {
        sum1=5;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }else if (coun1 == 198 ) {
        sum1=6;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }else if (coun1 == 231 ) {
        sum1=7;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }else if (coun1 == 264 ) {
        sum1=8;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }else if (coun1 == 297 ) {
        sum1=9;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }else if (coun1 == 330 ) {
        sum1=10;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }
}

public void sb(View view) {
    coun2++;
    textView1.setText(String.valueOf(coun2));
    if (coun2 == 33 ) {
        sum2=1;
        textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    }else if (coun2 == 66 ) {
        sum2=2;
        textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    }else if (coun2 == 99 ) {
        sum2=3;
        textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    }else if (coun2 == 132 ) {
        sum2=4;
        textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    }else if (coun2 == 165 ) {
        sum2=5;
        textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    }else if (coun2 == 198 ) {
        sum2=6;
        textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    }else if (coun2 == 231 ) {
        sum2=7;
        textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    }else if (coun2 == 264 ) {
        sum2=8;
        textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    }else if (coun2 == 297 ) {
        sum2=9;
        textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    }else if (coun2 == 330 ) {
        sum2=10;
        textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    }
}

public void hm (View view) {
    coun3++;
    textView2.setText(String.valueOf(coun3));
    if (coun3 == 33 ) {
        sum3=1;
        textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }else if (coun3 == 66 ) {
        sum3=2;
        textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }else if (coun3 == 99 ) {
        sum3=3;
        textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }else if (coun3 == 132 ) {
        sum3=4;
        textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }else if (coun3 == 165 ) {
        sum3=5;
        textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }else if (coun3 == 198 ) {
        sum3=6;
        textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }else if (coun3 == 231 ) {
        sum3=7;
        textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }else if (coun3 == 264 ) {
        sum3=8;
        textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }else if (coun3 == 297 ) {
        sum3=9;
        textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }else if (coun3 == 330 ) {
        sum3=10;
        textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }
}
public void stop(View view) {
    coun1=0;
    coun2=0;
    coun3=0;
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(coun1));
    textView1.setText(String.valueOf(coun2));
    textView2.setText(String.valueOf(coun3));
}

public void stop_sum(View view) {
    sum1=0;
    sum2=0;
    sum3=0;
    textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    textView_sum1.setText(String.valueOf(sum2));
    textView_sum2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the click event that calls the counter methods?

Comment: I'm using public void onClick instead of a listener, but it seems that I posted a wrong question and I apologize for that. my program displays the number 1 after I click on the button 33 times. Until it it displays the number 10 after I click the button 330 times. So every increment of 33 adds to the number one till it reaches 10. Problem is when I click another 33 times the displayed number doesn't increment to 11. I want the displayed number to increment to infinity with every 33 clicks. Kindly help me with that.

Comment: So you have 3 buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

If you show me the code where you optain reference to the buttons I can come up with a better solution than this one

```
public void s5(View view) {
    coun1++;
    coun1 %= 33;
    if (coun1 == 0) {
        sum1++;
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(sum1));
    }
}

public void sb(View view) {
    coun2++;
    coun2 %= 33;
    if (coun2 == 0) {
        sum2++;
        textView1.setText(String.valueOf(coun2));
    }
}

public void hm (View view) {
    coun3++;
    coun3 %= 33;
    if (coun3 == 0) {
        sum3++;
        textView2.setText(String.valueOf(sum3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this all I got in my code. To make it simple I'm looking for the best code possible as much as I'm looking for a functioning code that works.

Comment: you mean that this code is not working ?
Also if you have posted all your code where is the `public void onClick` method you mentioned earlier ?

Comment: utton bhome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bh);
    bhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();

Comment: No don't get me wrong the code is working fine. It's just that u said that u can come up with a better solution but ur code managed to run things well. Thank you very much

Comment: That's great, I have only one question what calls your `s5(view)`, `sb(view)` and `hm(view)` methods ?